# How to select an image having or not having particular 'alt' attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have many .png images and want to get a mentioned name where the alternative text is provided and if not mentioned in alt tag it should show 'png-image'.

Below code is just putting all the png images's alternate text 'png-image'.

Suppose I have an alt text for image i.e. `alt="facebook"` it should show `alt="facebook"` in place of `alt="png-image"`.

Through View Source it is showing `alt="facebook"` in place of `alt="png-image"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // apply Image alt attribute
            $('img[src$=".png"]').attr('alt', 'png-image');
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: suppose i have a png image alt="facebook" it should show alt="facebook" in place of "png-image"
but in view source it is showing "png-image" in place of alt="facebook" .

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.each` method to loop over all your images with `.png` at the end of its `src`. At each image, you can then check if it has an `alt` attribute using:

```
if(!$(this).attr('alt'))
```

If the image doesn't currently have an `alt` this `if` statement will run and so you can then add your own `alt` attribute to image.

See working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img[src$=".png"]').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).attr('alt')) // check if current image tag has alt attribute
      $(this).attr('alt', 'png-image'); // if it doesn't add 'png-image' alt attribute
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="foo.png" /><br />
<img src="bar.png" alt="this is my own alt" /><br />
<img src="foo2.png" alt="this is my own alt2" /><br />
<img src="foo.png" />
```

This will work for both cases where the `alt` attribute is either not set, or set to nothing (ie: `alt=""`)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[alt=""]` selector with the current selector

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // apply Image alt attribute
    $('img[src$=".png"][alt=""]').attr('alt', 'png-image');

  });

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/599708/pexels-photo-599708.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' alt='image'>
<img src='https://fnetobits.s3.amazonaws.com/galleries/boyerfuneralhome/1819974/1138985594.png' alt=''>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute based selector in JQuery to get all the img tags not having alt attribute,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img[src$=".png"][alt='']').attr('alt','png-image');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Sir
I want to know will above mentioned code work for both condition i.e. if alt="abcd" is mentioned then it will show "abcd" as alternative text but in case alt is not mentioned it will show png-image.

Comment: Yes, it will select all the images having no `alt` attribute and will set "png-image" as `alt` for those.